# split separador Javascript

Tags: javascript, funciones, split

Tengo que escribir una función en la que le pase un nombre completo (string) y me devuelva el nombre abreviado (el nombre y la primera letra del primer apellido, seguido de un punto) -> es decir, tecleo Pepito Perez y me tiene que devolver Pepito P.

Estoy un poco confuso con el tema de las posiciones, para que realice la separación y demás:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>funciones</title>
</head> 
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var nombre = prompt("Introduce nombre y apellidos");

function nombreCompleto(nombre) {
    var separa = nombre.split(".");
    //var nombre = separa[0];
}

function nombreCompleto();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Al usar [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split) debes decirle el separador, en tu caso sería un espacio

Comment: Cuidado con como haces el split, si el nombre es compuesto o el apellido lleva artículos no va a funcionar cortar por el primer espacio y coger la primera letra de la siguiente palabra

Comment: Por otra parte estás llamando mal a la función, debería ser `nombreCompleto();` simplemente, la palabra clave `function` se usa solo para crear la función

Comment: Buena aclaración Carmen, lo tendré en cuenta. Respecto a lo que comenta Blonfu, eso ha sido un error mío grave por despiste, aún así muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

El split convierte un string en un array partiendo el string desde la clave que le demos.

En tu caso lo del punto es algo que necesitas al final, por lo que el split lo dedes de hacer del espacio en blando para que te separe el nombre y el apellido.

Una vez que tengamos separados en la posición 0 del array el nombre y en la 1 el apellido solo falta concatenarlo y añadirle el factor de que coja la primera letra del apellido y le añada el punto.

Todo esto se haría así:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>funciones</title>
</head> 
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var nombre = prompt("Introduce nombre y apellidos");

var separa = nombre.split(" ");
var nombre = separa[0] + " " + separa[1].charAt(0) + ".";

alert(nombre);



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

estas usando mal [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split).

Esta función, debe usarse de la siguiente manera:

Según la [documentación de mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split) la función tiene la siguiente sintaxis

> ```
> cadena.split([separador][,limite])
> ```
>
> ***Dónde***
>
> *separador*
>
> Especifica el carácter a usar para la separación de la cadena. El
>   separador es tratado como una cadena o como una expresión regular. Si
>   se omite el separador, el array devuelto contendrá un sólo elemento
>   con la cadena completa.
>
> *limite*
>
> Opcional. Entero que especifica un límite sobre el número de
>   divisiones a realizar. El método split() todavía se divide en todas
>   las concordancias del separador, pero divide la matriz devuelta en la
>   cantidad de elementos impuesta por el limite.

---

Llevando esto a tu caso particular, se entiende que tener un error en la siguiente línea

```
var separa = nombre.split(".");
```

donde lo correcto, sería

```
var separa = nombre.split(" ",2);
```

Como podes ver, use la función `split()` con 2 argumentos, donde, como primer parámetro le pase un espacio, ya que el nombre estará separado por un espacio, y como segundo parámetro le pase un entero `2`, ya que espero que sólo sean dos palabras las que recibo.

Por lo que produciría lo siguiente

```
nombre: Marcos Perez 
separa[0]: Marcos
separa[1]: Perez

nombre: Gonzalo Martinez Gomez
separa[0]: Gonzalo
separa[1]: Martinez
separa[2]: no existe debido al segundo parámetro de split()
```

Luego, ya habiendo logrado separar el nombre y el apellido, solo bastaría, concatenar `separa[0]` con el primer caracter de `separa[1]`

```
var resultado = separa[0] + " " + separa[1].charAt(0)+".";
```